# Jsoup avoid unescpaing

Tags: jsoup

I have an HTML page with the follwoing content

> italiane &acirc;&#128;&#148; Ufficio

that I retrieve with

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(myLocation).get()
```

then extract some part as String with

```
    doc.outputSettings().indentAmount(0).prettyPrint(false);
    final Element docContent = doc.selectFirst("#docContent");
    return docContent.html();
```

Problem is that instead of having the raw html (as upper), I get the visual version as below

> italiane — Ufficio

I tried to change the escaping mode without success. How could it be achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was coming from remote content sending UTF-8 content but declaring it as ISO-8859-1

Solution was to fix remote server or use hereafter workaround

```
return new String(Jsoup.connect(remoteUrl).ignoreContentType(true).method(Connection.Method.GET).execute().bodyAsBytes(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```